# Google Cloud Messaging / GCM

Tags: java, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I wanted to add GCM to my application but I have some problems with the manifest.
This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.comanderkai77.gssvertretungsplan"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <permission
        android:name="de.comanderkai77.gssvertretungsplan.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="de.comanderkai77.gssvertretungsplan.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <service android:name=".GCM" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="de.comanderkai77.gssvertretungsplan" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".GCM_Intent" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The Java code is okay. When I call GCMRegistrar.register(MainActivity.this, GCM.SENDER_ID); nothing happens. The logcat say nothing useful. Do you have an idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GCMRegistrar](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.html) seems deprecated.

You can try [GoogleCloudMessaging](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html) : But, This class requires Google Play services version 3.1 or higher.

There is a useful code block in GoogleCloudMessaging doc page. So you will get something useful to know what is the problem may be you can't reach googlecloudmessaging service or something else, wrap your code with like these error control statements.

```
// Check device for Play Services APK. If check succeeds, proceed with
//  GCM registration.
if (checkPlayServices()) {
   gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
   regid = getRegistrationId(context);

   if (regid.isEmpty()) {
       registerInBackground();
   }
 } else {
   Log.i(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
 }
```

By the way you should check , is it communicating with gcm correctly? Is it returning registerId of the device or any error with its code.